# Async web requests are making 'socket hangup' in node.js

Tags: node.js, cheerio, node-request

I am writing a code that 'for' loops a large number of time to scrape web pages. Code is like:

```
var request = require('request');
for(i=0; i<10000; i++){
//request goes here, with processing in its callback
}
```

But this causes socket hangup. Then I tried [sync request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request) to do this then code works fine and processes request by request but this is making execution hell slow. Please guide how can large number of web requests can be processed for scraping for example.

Comment: You should look at option `agent`. Set it `false` or increase its `maxSockets` value

Comment: Thanks mr. d can you provide any reference to documentation or something. Sorry but I am new to node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at option `pool` when send a request using `request` module.

There are 3 options:

- Set it `false`
- Increase its `maxSockets`
- Increase http.globalAgent.maxSockets

Examples:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
   // make a request
   request({
      pool: false,
      // other options
   }, function(err, res, body) {
       // handle response here
   });
}
```

References:

- http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent
- https://github.com/request/request
- [How to use Request js (Node js Module) pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043355/how-to-use-request-js-node-js-module-pools)

Comment: Thanks mr.d you are great. I also added this code don't know of any help or not `var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = your_val_here;`

Comment: If you send https request and use globalAgent, it is neccessary.