# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I'm trying to call REST API asynchronously in a for loop using XMLHttpRequest module. I'm making 400 requests in 1 loop, with a wait time of 1 sec after every 100 requests. This works fine on clientside JavaScript. However, when I run on NodeJS using the same module (it's not natively available, I had to download from npmjs) , I'm getting this error after about 230 requests. Any idea if there is another module that I can use to better handle this bulk API requests?

> **Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]**

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4419

Comment: I used the keepaliveavent mentioned in this blog but still get this error. Strange how this works on client side and not on server side. May be I should use different module instead of XMLHttprequest.

Comment: The module where its timing out is (net.js:1161:14). Complete error is shown below:

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 15.125.324.173:443 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1161:14)

Answer (score 9):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

When using request module for calling REST APIs , you need to specify pool variable in the options. This serves as maxsockets, which is a declaration for concurrent request processing.

Sample code is posted below for those who run unto this issue:

For more info, check out below post:
[How to use Request js (Node js Module) pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043355/how-to-use-request-js-node-js-module-pools)

```js
var separateReqPool = {maxSockets: 20};
var request = require('request');
var url_array = ['url1','url2','url3'];//Array of all the urls to call


async.map(url_array, function(item, callback){
      request({url: item, pool: separateReqPool}, function (error, response, body) {
          //Do Something with the response
          });
        }, function(err, results){
          console.log(results);
        });
     }).
     catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
 });
```

Comment: Getting error like { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xx
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1082:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: xxx.xxx.xx,
  port: 3010 }