# How can I complete the Sanity init while error during "resolving latest module versions" keeps appearing

Tags: node.js, sanity

When trying to init Sanity I keep getting this error during the "resolving latest module versions" step.
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxx
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53339823/error-connect-etimedout-at-tcpconnectwrap-afterconnect-as-oncomplete) something about specifying the pool variable in options. Without access to the referred file, what can I do to complete the init?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this specific error was caused by the use of a VPN or Proxy. Turning it off fixed it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).